# how to get value form child in parent component using react-hook-form in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I want to get image and input value on submit

```
export const ImageUpload = ({onChange,imageName}) =>
{
    const {register} = useForm() 
    return <input type='file' id='single' onChange={onChange} {...register({imageName})} />        
}
```

submit function

```
  const {register, handleSubmit} = useForm()
  const onSubmit = async (data) => console.log(data)
```

parent Component

```
 <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
     <input{...register({username})} />
     <ImageUpload imageName='imgone' />
     <Button  type="submit"> Submit </Button>              
 </form>
```

Comment: You seem not to pass onChange callback function to ImageUpload.